# Pyqt widget FigureCanvas border and content coexist

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt

i want a widget,it can use matplotlib drawing an image and it can setting it's border.

so i'm create a class，it's parent is FigureCanvas,that i can drawing image.
It seems that setting a border must be rewrite paintEvent method，so i do.
But i find when i rewrite paintEvent method，drawing failed.

When i note the paintEvent method method，drawing success.

Who can help me improve the code or give me some tips.

```
import pydicom
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from matplotlib.backends.backend_template import FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.pylab import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas


class InstancesFC(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self):
        self.figure = plt.figure(figsize=(2, 2))
        super(InstancesFC, self).__init__(self.figure)
        self.update_area()
        self.setObjectName('InstancesFC')
        self.ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        plt.axis('off')
        x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
        y = [23, 21, 32, 13, 3, 132, 13, 3, 1]
        self.ax.plot(x, y)

    def update_area(self):
        self.setStyleSheet("""
            #InstancesFC{
                          border-width: 1px;
             border-style: solid;
             border-color: red;
             min-width:%s;
             max-width:%s;
             min-height:%s;
             max-height:%s;
             padding:0px;
             margin:1px;
            }
        """ % ('300px', '300px', '300px', '300px'))

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        opt = QStyleOption()
        opt.initFrom(self)
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        self.style().drawPrimitive(QStyle.PE_Widget, opt, painter, self)


class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        h = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        h.addWidget(InstancesFC())
        self.setLayout(h)
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 500, 500)
        self.show()


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you override the paintEvent() method and if you don't call the parent method then you will eliminate the default behavior causing the problem you are observing. The solution is to call the paintEvent() method of the parent.

```
def paintEvent(self, event):
    super(InstancesFC, self).paintEvent(event)
    opt = QStyleOption()
    opt.initFrom(self)
    painter = QPainter(self)
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
    self.style().drawPrimitive(QStyle.PE_Widget, opt, painter, self)
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, I now have another problem. I overridden paintEvent in my project according to your method, and call the parent's paintEvent with super, but I found that there are several cases of overriding paintEvent. First, super Then execute my code in paintEvent. There is no picture in the border. Second, first execute my code in paintEvent and then call super. If there is no picture in the box, I still do n’t quite understand. Is it because of a problem in my project environment? This new question

Comment: @redj I do not understand you, if you have a new question then you must publish a new post.

Comment: Ok，Let me think for myself, it really does n’t work. I will post my question, mainly because it is difficult for me to reproduce it with a small case now.

Comment: Hello friends, this is my new question, the link is here, can you give me some valuable comments?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60315472/does-pyqt-add-top-level-styles